# Controlling visibility of wicket component via AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I'm using Wicket 8.10.

I have a Wicket Component that I want to dynamically hide or show depending on some external condition. For that I have the following code:

```java
var mccc = new MyCoolCustomComponent("component"); // Custom component I wrote
mccc.setOutputMarkupId(true);
mccc.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
mccc.setVisible(false); //Should be hidden initially

var container = new WebMarkupContainer("container");
container.setOutputMarkupId(true);
container.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
container.add(mccc);

add(container);

var updateTimer = new AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(1)) {
  @Override
  protected void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    if(FooSingleton.instance().isBar()) {
      mccc.setVisible(true);
    } else {
      mccc.setVisible(false);
    }
    target.add(mccc);
  }
};
container.add(updateTimer);
```

The corresponding HTML looks like this:

```html
<div wicket:id="container" >
    <div wicket:id="component"/>
</div>
```

What I would expect to happen: The component is hidden initially. When `isBar()` returns `true` the component is shown and once it returns `false` again it is hidden.

What is actually happening: The component is hidden initially. It is shown once `isBar()` becomes `true` but *does not* become invisible once `isBar()` returns `false`.

---

I also thought about using an `AttributeModifier` to use the CSS `display` property, but I can't find how to change the value of the modifier.

Comment: That should work as intended. You could take a look at your browser's network tab and check for the content of the Ajax response - this way you see whether the problem lies in the browser or on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with CSS:

```java
mccc.add(new AttributeModifier("style",
  () -> {
    if (FooSingleton.instance().isBar()) {
      return "";
    }
    return "display: none;";
  }));
```

I'm sure the solution is not great, but it works for now.

Comment: `var state` seems unused. I guess you can remove it from the lambda body.

Comment: Yup, that was from my actual code. I try to condense it as much as possible so people can see the problem and not get distracted by other things.